# Gnuplot histogram with plot line

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot to create a histogram with a plot line, however, the plot line is not fit well with bar head, also I would like to put the line a little bit far from the bar head.

[image]

```
set border 3 
set boxwidth 0.9
set tics nomirror out scale 0.75
set style fill solid 0.8

plot "03.txt" using 2:xtic(1) lt rgb "#0060ad" notitle, "" using 2 smooth csplines notitle with lines ls 1, "" using 3 lt rgb "#ff6600" notitle, "" using 3 smooth csplines notitle with lines ls 2, "" using 4 lt rgb "#dd181f" notitle, "" using 4 smooth csplines notitle with lines ls 3
```

Updated:

This is the data file:

```
500000      25.938          25.938      2
1000000     52.385          52.385      4
1500000     79.749          78.405      6.125
2000000     152.589         100.261     12.479
2500000     224.869         118.364     19.159
```

Comment: It's always better to post your datafile (or a significant part of it). I believe you'll achieve what you want with some tuning of the splines's `using` clause, but there could be some influence of the content of your column 2 on an easy choice. By "put the line a little bit far from the bar head", do you mean a vertical shift of the whole spline ?

Comment: @Joce I added the data file, yes, I need a vertical shift to avoid sticking the plot line with bars head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for any number of columns, you have to specify them in the variable `N`, and number them in calls to custom function `xbox`. This should do for a non-intensive usage. You can offset vertically the curves with the `OFFSET` variable (in units of y axis)

```
set border 3
#number of columns to be plotted
N=3
#vertical offset
OFFSET=0
#gapwidth (set to gnuplot's default)
GW=2
xbox(x,i)=x+(i-N*0.5)/(N+GW)
set boxwidth 0.9
set tics nomirror out scale 0.75
set style fill solid 0.8

plot "03.txt" using 2:xtic(1) lt rgb "0060ad" notitle,  \
         "" using 2 with histogram notitle,     \
         "" using (xbox($0,1)):($2+OFFSET) smooth csplines notitle with lines ls 1,     \
         "" using 3 lt rgb "#ff6600" notitle with histogram,    \
         "" using (xbox($0,2)):($3+OFFSET) smooth csplines notitle with lines ls 2,     \
         "" using 4 lt rgb "#dd181f" notitle with histogram,    \
         "" using (xbox($0,3)):($4+OFFSET) smooth csplines notitle with lines ls 3
```